# Why is ext4 offered as the default filesystem if Theodore Ts'o said this about it?

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, ext4, defaults

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#ext4) that

> In 2008, Ts'o [the designer of ext3 and ext4] stated that although ext4 has improved features such as being much faster than ext3, it is not a major advance, it uses old technology, and is a stop-gap; Ts'o believes that Btrfs is the better direction, because "it offers improvements in scalability, reliability, and ease of management" <sup>[45](https://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/04/linux-collaboration-summit-the-kernel-panel.ars)</sup>

So, how come many/most Linux distributions still offer ext4 as the default file system when installing a new system?

Comment: My question would be: Why bother with something said in 2008?

Comment: @Plergux: Because if that was true in 2008, it should probably be even more true after 13 years. I mean, not necessarily the btrfs  choice, but the evaluation of ext4.

Comment: Not necessarily, Ext4 development didn’t stop in 2008.

Comment: Well, considering that as far as I know Ts'o is the maintainer of ext4 he might have done something for it.

Comment: @Plergux: But it's very backwards-compatible. I think that's why that comment was made. Also, JiriB suggests it is "super stable", so likely not much done with it.

Comment: @einpoklum well, to me backwards-compatible is a beautiful thing. But that clearly isn't everybodies cup of tea. :p

Comment: I'm not sure if we have evidence to answer this question, but I'll point to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18388/117549 from 2011 which claims "Btrfs has begun to gain some momentum in replacing ext4 as the default filesystem of choice for a few distributions such as Fedora Core 16" and https://access.redhat.com/articles/3129891#:~:text=The%20XFS%20File%20System,Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%207. where XFS is the default for RHEL7.

Comment: @Plergux: I didn't say it's necessarily a bad thing, but it does preclude many fundamental changes.

Comment: @einpoklum well, some of us are old and like old things :p

Comment: this is a good question.  I would love to here *official* answers from RHEL, SLES, UBUNTU, and others on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's super stable. BTW see list and characteristics of filesystems at https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP2/html/SLES-all/cha-filesystems.html

Comment: Stability is a good answer. But - is this the thinking for distribution maintainers, or is this why you believe it is a good choice?

Comment: There's nothing like general view of distribution maintainers. RHEL prefers XFS, SUSE prefers BTRFS (for OS), no idea for other distributions and their defaults. BTW, every advanced user should be able to install its preferred distro on a filesystem of his preference.